# How do you fix the http:502.5 error when using Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've written my website using Visual Studio 2017 and I'm trying to publish it to a hostgator windows server. The issue that I'm having is that now that I've published it to the server the website doesn't load, and I keep getting an http:502.5 error.

My question is: how do I fix this error, what code do I need to write to fix this?

Comment: two points. one we generally prefer to avoid images, two you didn't actually add an image.

Comment: Gilliduck yea I know it wouldn’t let me add an image because of my reputation sorry about that

Comment: @Nino error 502 means bad gateway. I assume either you've made a mistake with the route or with the configuration of the webserver. But without more details there isn't much that we can do.

Comment: Is this a Core application? 502.5 Process Failure happens when the ASP.NET Core Module attempts to start the backend dotnet process but it fails to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the expected port is not in use already.

Worth taking a look at [Process Failure in ASP.NET Core](http://dotnet4europeanhosting.hostforlife.eu/post/European-ASPNET-Core-Hosting-HostForLIFEeu-How-to-Fix-Error-5025-Process-Failure-in-ASPNET-Core.aspx)